# Eclipse RAP Web Application and Google AdSense Integration

Tags: adsense, eclipse-rap

I am planning to develop a website in Eclipse RAP, as I am a Eclipse fan and know bit of RCP. And I would like to make use of the Google AdSense so that commercial ads can be displayed in my web site. As RAP is bit different from regular web applications, I would like to know whether Google AdSense can be used in my RAP based web site.
Also I came across some news regarding the restriction on number of concurrent sessions in RAP based web applications. What is the maximum limit? Will it be improved in the newer versions in future? Kindly clarify the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about AdSense specifically, but you should have a look at the `Browser` widget. It's a widget that can contain any HTML/JS and renders as an IFRAME in the web browser.

**Update:** as a workaround, you could add an HTML element in a JavaScript snippet that you send to the client using `JavaScriptExecutor`. This snippet could append an element to the `document` using plain DOM API, or append an element to a RAP widget using the RAP client API. Have a look at [rap.getObject()](http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/doc/3.0/guide/reference/jsdoc/symbols/rap.html) and [Widget.$el](http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/doc/3.0/guide/reference/jsdoc/symbols/Widget.html).

Yet another approach would be to develop a [custom widget](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=custom-widget.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked with AdSense forums and as per their policies

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my RCP application, the EditPart/ViewPart region contains Browser widget in which I load dynamically generated HTML content along with the adSense content. As you mentioned, if creates IFRAME during run time for the browser widget content.  Unfortunately, when I checked with AdSense forums,  as per their policies, we are not supposed to have the ad content inside IFRAME. Is there any way we can avoid IFrame and have normal HTML frames in RAP?

Comment: @RosarioPoulraj I see. Please see my updated answer for alternatives.